# How do I generate nested table in one column if it has list of values using angular js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

index.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.data =[{"Id":1,"Title":"en-US","Description":"UnitedStates","MyValues":[{"Id":100,"Value":"Save"}]},
{"Id":1,"Title":"en-UK","Description":"UK","MyValues":[{"Id":102,"Value":"Delete"}]}]
  $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);

  $scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
});
```

index.html

```
<table border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="key in notSorted(cols)" ng-init="value=cols[key]">{{value}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
          <td ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat="dat in notSorted(row)" ng-init="value=row[dat]">{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

It gives me perfect table but problem is in one column `MyValues`.
I have list of data and want to create nested table with all List value.

> How can I achieve this?  Want to check if any column has List if yes
>   then generate nested table.
>   check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Ixvp8B0dRwOBDHflmu2j?p=preview

Comment: How deeply nested can your data get?

Comment: only one step nothing more than that
like MyValues other column can have same data

Comment: Join the angularjs chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write your markup this way:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="(k,v) in data[0]">{{k}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
      <td ng-repeat="(prop, value) in item" ng-init="isArr = isArray(value)">
        <table ng-if="isArr">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th ng-repeat="(sh, sv) in value[0]">{{sh}}</th>
            </tr> 
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="sub in value">
              <td ng-repeat="(sk, sv) in sub">{{sv}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <span ng-if="!isArr">{{value}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/487956892d760c17487c

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you want to render, but this might give you some ideas.

see: http://plnkr.co/edit/znswagx45a2F7IThdQJn?p=preview

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data =[{"Id":1,"Title":"en-US","Description":"UnitedStates","MyValues":[{"Id":100,"Value":"Save"}]},
{"Id":1,"Title":"en-UK","Description":"UK","MyValues":[{"Id":102,"Value":"Delete"}]}]
  $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);

  $scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}  
});
```

index.html

```
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="key in notSorted(cols)" ng-init="value=cols[key]">{{value}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
      <td ng-if="!$last" ng-repeat="dat in notSorted(row)" ng-init="value=row[dat]">
        <div ng-if="value[0].Id">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Id:</td><td>{{value[0].Id}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Value:</td><td>{{value[0].Value}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!(value[0].Id)">
          {{value}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to be more general, maybe instead of `<div ng-if="value[0].Id">` you could do something like `<div ng-if="angular.isArray(value)">`.  I didn't have time to try and get that working though, but something to look into.

Comment: thanks for quick reply but i do not want to specify column names                   `<td>Id:</td><td>{{value[0].Id}}</td>` as it will be anything that is why want a dynamic solution like how main table value gets bind in that same way want to generate internal table also, guide me thanks in advance

Comment: I added at the bottom, you should be able to do `<div ng-if="angular.isArray(value)">` or something similar to know it's an array / collection, but I didn't have time to play around with getting it working.

Comment: can I have any similar thread :( I tried but i;n newbie in angular i failed to do so.