# how to check in json data for any column value is there array/collection present using angular js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

index.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data =[{"Id":1,"Title":"en-US","Description":"UnitedStates","MyValues":[{"demo":"dish","Id":100,"Value":"Save"}]},
{"Id":1,"Title":"en-UK","Description":"UK","MyValues":[{"demo":"Myvalu","Id":102,"Value":"Delete"}]}]
  $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.data[0]);

  $scope.notSorted = function(obj){
    if (!obj) {
        return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}  
});
```

> I want to check in `$scope.data` is there any column value as array/collection
>   in above code `MyValues` is a `array/collection` , I tried using
>   `angular.isArray(value)` but it does not work , any help?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are just trying to determine if $scope.data is an array?

Comment: yes i'm trying to determine in $scope.data is there a array/collection present for any column value

Comment: so, Array.isArray($scope.data) ? Or something else?

Comment: I tried the same :( any live example would be helpful thanks

Comment: Try these approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript.

Comment: Array.isArray($scope.data) will tell you if $scope.data is an array. Are you trying to determine if something INSIDE of $scope.data is an array?

Comment: `$scope.data.length > 0` maybe? I am also confused. lol

Comment: Looks like Ahmed gave a perfect answer, as far as I understand the question at least

Comment: @shieldstroy yes, i want to check whether $scope.data is having any column as array/collection or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this check **Array.isArray([1,2,3])**

```
$scope.data.map(function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k){
       return Array.isArray(obj[k]);
    });
});
```

The code above will give you all the lists for each element in the Array of **$scope.data** ,, do you want a specific format ??

Comment: yup its work as expected actually I tried this to find out answer for this question check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447821/how-do-i-generate-nested-table-in-one-column-if-it-has-list-of-values-using-angu

Comment: if you able to answer this question also it will be great help thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447821/how-do-i-generate-nested-table-in-one-column-if-it-has-list-of-values-using-angu

Answer (score 1):

Better technique is to use the `some()` with `angular.isArray()`:

```
if($scope.data.some(angular.isArray)) {
   //do awesome stuff
}
```

Comment: but how do I used this in table tag? in html?

Comment: i tried to achieve this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447821/how-do-i-generate-nested-table-in-one-column-if-it-has-list-of-values-using-angu