# How would you ng-repeat this

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I also would like to display the keys "scott" and "bill" and all their property values(fullname and age) using ng-repeat.

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "scott": {
            "fullname": "Scott D Man",
            "age": "string"
        },
        "bill": {
            "fullname": "William Shatner",
            "age": "string"
        }
    },
    "id": "HJK321",
    "reportDate": "20150719"
}
```

Comment: have a look at this for an idea...http://stackoverflow.com/a/31489211/145682

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate on the object properties like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in model.attributes">
    <span>Name : {{key}}</span>
    <span>Full Name : {{value.fullname}}</span>
    <span>Age : {{value.age}}</span>
</div>
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzcSh9vSRnsO0VGTYdu3?p=preview)

Comment: What if using <input> and not <span> and also making key as the ng-model?

Comment: I will post another question. I noticed that my JSON was suppose to use array as oppose to object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <p>Your Data:</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.attributes">
            firstname: {{key}}, fullname: {{value.fullname}}, age: {{value.age}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyzsw565/

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div ng-repeat='(user, description) in data.attributes'>
      {{user}}
      <div ng-repeat='(key, val) in description'>
        <span>{{key}} : {{val}}</span>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this working  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2y8hu4y/)

```
  <div ng-app="mainApp">
     <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-repeat="d in data">

           Name:      {{d.attributes.scott.fullname}}  ,        
           Age :      {{d.attributes.scott.age}}    

            Name:      {{d.attributes.bill.fullname}}  ,        
            Age :      {{d.attributes.bill.age}}    

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it will work but it will become a nightmare in terms of refactoring every time there is a change in data